# Parsing A Screenplay

Tags: python, regex, parsing

Hi im trying to parse out a screenplay and trying to capture (NAME) : (Dialogue) with regex. So far on regex 101 I have `re.complie('(\w+)\n(.*)')` but as you'll see in the image it falls flat for certain lines containing special characters. Any help is appreciated. (added text format to help reproducibility)[image]

```
                 CLAIRE
      Morning, beauty.

Caitlin lets out a grunt and rolls over onto her belly.

                 CLAIRE
      Let's go.  Or we'll never leave on time.

From out of the pillow comes Caitlin's voice.

                 CAITLIN
           (muffled)
      I'm totally ready.

Claire glances around at the piles of unpacked clothes.

                 CLAIRE
      Come on, I'll make you some waffles,
      maybe we'll squeeze in a trip to the
      mall.
           (beat)
      Caitlin...
```

Comment: You have not explained what output you expect. Does `(?m)^\s*\b([A-Z]+)\b\s*\n(.*(?:\n.+)*)` work for you? See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Mmtsuj/2).

Comment: Thanks, @WiktorStribiżew that's perfect it captures the NAME in group one and all of the DIALOGUE in group two. My desired output is a dictionary with keys being group one and values being group two. I had used the pattern in the OP and wrote out the code to do this. Now with your pattern its perfect thanks a lot. I will post the full answer in case some else in need stumble across it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?m)^\s*\b([A-Z]+)\b\s*\n(.*(?:\n.+)*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Mmtsuj/2).

**Details**:

- `(?m)^`  - start of a line (`(?m)` is the same as the `re.M` option)
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\b([A-Z]+)\b` - Group 1: an uppercase whole word (`\b` are word boundaries)
- `\s*`
- `\n` - a newline char
- `(.*(?:\n.+)*)` - Group 2: the rest of a line, then zero or more sequences of a newline and then the rest of the line (so, any text up to the first blank line).

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/GlZIct):

```py
import re
rx = r"^\s*\b([A-Z]+)\b\s*\n(.*(?:\n.+)*)"
text = "                 CLAIRE\n      Morning, beauty.\n\nCaitlin lets out a grunt and rolls over onto her belly.\n\n                 CLAIRE\n      Let's go.  Or we'll never leave on time.\n\nFrom out of the pillow comes Caitlin's voice.\n\n                 CAITLIN\n           (muffled)\n      I'm totally ready.\n\nClaire glances around at the piles of unpacked clothes.\n\n                 CLAIRE\n      Come on, I'll make you some waffles,\n      maybe we'll squeeze in a trip to the\n      mall.\n           (beat)\n      Caitlin..."
print( re.findall(rx, text, re.M) )
```

Output:

```
[
  ('CLAIRE', '      Morning, beauty.'),
  ('CLAIRE', "      Let's go.  Or we'll never leave on time."),
  ('CAITLIN', "           (muffled)\n      I'm totally ready."),
  ('CLAIRE', "      Come on, I'll make you some waffles,\n      maybe we'll squeeze in a trip to the\n      mall.\n           (beat)\n      Caitlin...")
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Some issues I see right away:

- You are not leveraging the fact that the character name is all caps.  Use `[A-Z]+` instead of `\w+` in your regex for that.
- You are not using the `SingleLine` regex option, so that's preventing the `.` from matching multiple lines.

Comment: Yah I had [A-Z]+ in place already (still tinkering away on it right now) I'll look into the SingleLine regex option I've never heard that term before. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

The full code to achieve the desired result with thanks to @Wiktor Stribiżew for his pattern.

```
# Grouped regex pattern to capture char and dialouge in a tuple
char_dialogue = re.compile(r"(?m)^\s*\b([A-Z]+)\b\s*\n(.*(?:\n.+)*)")
extract_dialogue = char_dialogue.findall(script)

final_dict = {}

for element in extract_dialogue:
   # Seperating the character and dialogue from the tuple
   char = element[0]
   line = element[1]
   # If the char is already a key in the dictionary
   # and line is not empty append the dialogue to the value list
   if char in final_dict:
       if line != '':
           final_dict[char].append(line)
   else:
       # Else add the character name to the dictionary keys with their first line
       # Drop any lower case matches from group 0
       # Can adjust the len here if you have characters with fewer letters
       if char.isupper() and len(char) >2:
           final_dict[char] = [line]

        
# Some final cleaning to drop empty dalouge 

final_dict = {k: v for k, v in final_dict.items() if v  != ['']}

# More filtering to reutrn only main characters with more than 50 
# lines of dialogue 

final_dict = {k: v for k, v in final_dict.items() if len(v) > 50}
```